# Migrating from PHP 5.3.x to PHP 5.4.x

Tags: php

A simple test program program is included.

enter data into dataone
click on create system
dataone data moved to datatwo

works with 5.3

with 5.4 when the create system image is clicked 
 the data in dataone disappears from the form and noting is passed to datatwo

we have a large number of programs that use this method of input fields and images to click on.

If I shift to 5.3 it works.
If I shift to 5.4 it wil not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
</head>
<?php
$dataone = $HTTP_POST_VARS['dataone'];
$datatwo = $HTTP_POST_VARS['datatwo'];
if(isset($_POST['proc_x']))
{
 $datatwo = $dataone;
}  
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="test.php">
<table>
 <tr>
   <td><strong>
       One</strong>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input name="dataone" type="text"  id="dataone" 
   value="<?php echo  $dataone?>"      size="70">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><strong>
       two</strong>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><input name="datatwo" type="text" id="datatwo" 
    value="<?php echo $datatwo; ?>" size="70">
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="1"><div align="left" >
    <input name="proc" type="image" id="proc" value="proc"  alt="Create System" 
      title="Create  System" width="25" height="25">
      <strong>proc</strong></div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input name="inx" type="hidden" id="inx"
     value ="<?php echo $inx; ?>"     size="100">
    </td>  
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$HTTP_POST_VARS` was deprecated long ago.  I haven't actually seen anyone use it in nearly 10 years.  Use `$_POST` instead.

Also, you have opened yourself up to potential XSS attacks.  Always use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML.